# Is there any published research on the information-carrying capacity of the human face?

Tags: reference-request, human-like, facial-recognition, complexity-theory, information-theory

- Is there any published research on the information-carrying capacity of the human face?

Here I mean "how much information can be conveyed via facial expressions & micro-expressions".

This is a subject of interest because the human face is arguably "the most interesting" single thing for humans, since it's likely the first real pattern we recognize as infants, and conveys so much non-verbal communication than can relate to achievement of a goal or identification of a mortal threat.  (Dogs similarly are said to have co-evolved to read human faces. Film acting as "the art of the closeup" also validates this viewpoint.)

Essentially, I'm tying to get a sense of how complex is the set of human facial expressions, what is the computational complexity of the range of problems related to identification of the range of possible expressions, and the emulation of such expressions to imitate a human agent.  (i.e. these techniques can be used to "read" a human subject or manipulate a human subject.)

*Well researched articles & blogs would also be welcome.*